# Расширение COM интерфейса класса

Tags: com, c++

Ситуация следующая:
имеется COM интерфейс класса, необходимо расширить его с целью добавления propput для некоторых свойств.

Подскажите, как это правильно реализовать: наследоваться от данного интерфейса или же менять сам интерфейс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае нужно только наследовать или агрегировать. Но, если у Вас COM компонент находиться в стадии разработки или он используется только вашими программами, то может быть удобнее и проще поменять интерфейс на такой какой Вам нужен.